# When using bouncy castle as crypto provider and GCM, cipherOutputStream.close() doesn't seem to throw invalidCipherTextException

Tags: java, bouncycastle

When using Bouncy Castle as the provider and GCM if I have deliberately modified the cipher text an invalidCipherTextException should be thrown and if I step through in debug mode on cipherOutputStream.close() I can see the invalidCipherTextException however I cannot catch this exception.

```
               BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(user.encryptedDirectory.containedFiles.get(counter)));
                CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(user.unencryptedDirectory.location.toAbsolutePath() +  "\\"+ user.encryptedDirectory.containedFiles.get(counter).getName() + ""), cipher);
                copy(is,os);
                is.close();
                os.close();


    private static void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    int i;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while((i=is.read(b))!=-1) {
        os.write(b, 0, i);
    }

}
```

Do I need to rewrite so that cipher.doFinal() is called or am I misunderstanding something?